# Getting facebook friends profile pictures the fastest way - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get my friends pictures with FBConnect,
The requested URL is:

```
pictureURL =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=50&height=50", [data objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

And the image set here:

```
NSString *pictureUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self getProfileUrl:object]];
[friend setImage:pictureUrl];
```

the set method is:

```
NSData *pictureData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureUrl]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pictureData];
if (image != nil)
    friendImage = image;
```

Very simple,
But for a big amount of friends this process takes tooooooo long,
Is there a way to get the profile images faster, or more efficient than this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could get their profile picture in the same request you use to retrieve your friends like this:

```
/me/friends?fields=name,picture.type(large)
```

You get a response similar to this one:

```
{   "data": [
    {
      "name": "xxx", 
      "id": "42", 
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/image1.jpg",

          "is_silhouette": false
        }
      }
    }, 
    {
      "name": "xxx", 
      "id": "42", 
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/image2.jpg",

          "is_silhouette": false
        }
      }
    },
...
```

So you don't have to call Facebook for each of your friends. Also, i suggest you load your images asynchronously and this [great component](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) could be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I used SDWebImage, also from github, this made it alot easier

Comment: @assafey Glad you solved your problem. If you think my answer was useful, please consider accepting it ;-)

Comment: @assafey any idea why is my data array is empty? i only get a summary response with a key total_count.. Thanks

Comment: @assafey never mind, there is no way to get all the user's friends. Only those who have your app